# Stash only some of the currently modified files

Tags: git, git-stash

I have many changed files and would like to stash only some of the modified files.

As an example, my repository looks something like:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

      modified: main.cpp
      modified: MyClass.h
      modified: MyClass.cpp
```

And I would like to stash `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp` only.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3040833/9614249) but the accepted answer appears to be wrong and the most voted answer requires each hunk/file to be interactively added.

Is there an easy way to stash a specific set of files? Preferably in a single command without having to interactively select files one by one or stage/unstage things.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/49886083/2541573 ?

Comment: I had not but that still requires that you interactively select a set of changes in `git stash --patch` right?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found `git stash push` can be used to easily stash multiple files.

To stash the files from the example the command would be

```
 git stash push MyClass.h MyClass.cpp
```

Which stashes `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp` but leaves `main.cpp` alone.

Found in an edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5506483/9614249)

Comment: Nice find. I had overlooked `git stash push`.

Comment: `git stash push -- <paths>` is kind of nice, but be careful with it: it has a nasty bug of removing untracked files, not fixed until Git 2.16.2.

Comment: This is also suggested in the QA you linked to in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693541/1615903

Comment: Works on directories too `git stash push lib/`